# What German village is this on the Rhine River?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, rhine

I bought this painting, which is supposedly of a German village on the Rhine called *Clouds Above the Rhine* and I was wondering if anyone knew what city it is.

[image: clouds above the Rhine painting]

Comment: The painting is clearly this: https://afremov.com/germany-clouds-above-the-rhine-palette-knife-oil-painting-on-canvas-by-leonid-afremov-size-54-x40.html but I'm not sure if that's supposed to be a real place.

Answer (score 50):

[image]

This looks remarkably like the town I live in: Thun, Canton Bern, Switzerland! Not on the Rhine, but on the river Aare, which as it flows eventually arrives at the capital Bern. The photo above is my own, that I took especially to recreate the scene in the painting. Unfortunately, I cannot control the overcast conditions of a mid February Sunday.

Comment: [This](https://maps.app.goo.gl/GUJSXeuAdzsNqaRx5) is probably the closest you can get to the original on Google Maps.

Comment: do you have any evidence that the town was not built based upon the painting

Comment: @Turbo The church tower dates back to 1330 and the castle roof to 1430 but I suppose we can't rule out time travelers.

Comment: LOL @Turbo. Talk about life imitating art!

Comment: Wow. That's incredibly close!

Comment: While Thun is not on the Rhine, Aare is a tributary that leads onto the Rhine so with a little poetic license it does kind of fit with the title.

Answer (score 7):

While the painting is indeed a stylized Rheinland riverbank town, it might have, IMHO, been inspired by a river view of Eltville, not far from Mainz and Wiesbaden, on the right bank of the Rhine, south of Rüdesheim.

I was stationed in Wiesbaden and had many friends living there.

My favorite Eltville memory was a restaurant downtown that served kosher salted and herbed duck fat instead of butter with the basket of bread.

A Rhein cruise from Mainz to Koblenz on a sunny day is a great outing.

[image: Eltville Tower]